# Removing the focus from textbox before ajax request

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, focus

Hello all I am saving the data of a form at regular interval through javascript .
The code is something like that

```
SetInterval(function(){
$find("<%=AjaxManager1.ClientID%>").ajaxRequest("SaveData")
},20000)
```

In code behind I am writing the code for saving form data
There  are various control like, radtextbox,raddatepicker. etc...
The problem I am facing is the value  of a text box is not saved if it has a focus.
So I want to remove the focus from any of the textbox before the next ajax request initiates.

Comment: choose a control that does not contain user input, and focus() before you save.

Answer (score 0):

try this where ever you need

```
  $('textBoxSelector').blur();
```